# How do I set up a price range facet in Solr?

Tags: solr, facet

I have a situation where price is mentioned by user , imagine a re seller website . How do I set up a facet which takes into account the actual values of the prices field and sets up ranges accordingly ?

Prices are : 350 , 500 , 700 , 1300 , 1850 and so on .

Ranges are : 0-400 , 400-800 , 800-1200 , 1200-1600 , 1600-2000 .

Note : The price range cannot be fixed .

Comment: Check my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756583/price-range-filter-with-slider-ui-with-min-max-value-from-solr-in-same-query/38263030#38263030](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756583/price-range-filter-with-slider-ui-with-min-max-value-from-solr-in-same-query/38263030#38263030)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the "Facet by Range" parameters [here in the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#rangefaceting).

In your case they would probably be:

```
facet.range=price
facet.range.start=0
facet.range.end=2000
facet.range.gap=400
```

That `facet.range.end` might be unnecessary.

If you have some prices that are way above 2000, maybe 10000, you can have an "other" argument that counts everything outside the `facet.range`.

```
facet.range.other=after
```

This returns counts for everything above 2000.

Comment: Hey, Andy thanks for the answer . However this is not what I was looking for (maybe I should rephrase the question) . The problem is that I don't know start,end or gap . All three depend on user's data which is not monitored to determine these values . I will probably user application code to take care of this .