# Price Range Filter with Slider UI with Min & Max value from Solr in same query?

Tags: jquery, solr, solrj, solrnet

I'm working on an Solr integration for an e-commerce site. I want to offer a jQuery Slide Range UI (refer http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range).

So visitor will be offered with a slider with min and max price on the page which they can use to define a range and accordingly the filter is applied.

On Solr side, I understand how to make a range filter query on this.

However, for displaying a range I need min and max price value. I'm not sure how to get this from Solr.

Moreover, when other facets are filtered, I need to change this min & max price. But I can not think about how this can be done with Solr. Does solr provide min & max price value in the same query?

How to do this?

Or what is the best practices to implement this with Solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are already getting the facet values of current data set, 
so as for your range problem you have to sort the facet value on the client side and supply the min & max values to slider.

This way it resolves your other problem too, because with filters applied, the returned resultant values for facets will change too.

Moreover you can add an additional check for not showing sliders in case facets does n't return anything.

For large data ranges , i think you can use solr `stats` eg :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=price&rows=0&indent=on
```

Read here about it : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent

Comment: But suppose if a category has 10k products, and suppose all of them have different price. In such case Solr will return all of this 10k price value as a facet. And to do a client side processing, this will need to process all these values to find min & max price. Using this, it can be done. But this doesn't seems to be a decent solution. As communication between solr and app could be expensive (due to large data set). Can you think of any other way to do this?

Comment: well thats an interesting constraint, though you can sort the facet even on solr side using facet.sort=index, but for that large of a datasize , even solr will take considerable time to execute the query.

Comment: hi, I think this can be used! I'll try this and update shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solr version: 5.4 and above.

May be the post is old but definitely it will help some one.

I have a solution for this and I have implemented in my project.

You have to use json facet to achive the max and min value based on the facet result.

```
    json.facet={
   tags_group:{
      type:terms,
      field:tags,
      limit:-1,
      facet:{
         pricemin:{
            type:terms,
            field:price,
            limit:1,
            sort:{
               x:asc
            },
            facet:{
               x:"min(price)"
            }
         },
         pricemax:{
            type:terms,
            field:price,
            limit:1,
            sort:{
               y:desc
            },
            facet:{
               y:"max(price)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the above Json facet I have used tags as filed(multivalued) and this will create a bucket like this

```
<str name="val">Letter Holder</str>
<int name="count">2</int>
<lst name="pricemin">
    <arr name="buckets">
        <lst>
            <double name="val">899.0</double>
            <int name="count">1</int>
            <double name="x">899.0</double>
        </lst>
    </arr>
</lst>
<lst name="pricemax">
    <arr name="buckets">
        <lst>
            <double name="val">1299.0</double>
            <int name="count">1</int>
            <double name="y">1299.0</double>
        </lst>
    </arr>
</lst>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `stats` of SOLR, pass stats parameter to your SOLR query, here i pass grand_total in stats field to get min,max,count,mean,deviation etc.

[stats SOLR Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent)

```
http://<ip_address>:<port>/solr/<core_name>/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&stats=true&stats.field=grand_total
```